# react-native-responsive-fontsize not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, font-size

I am trying to build an application with react native but react-native-responsive-fontsize is not working. Like I am following the the steps from [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-fontsize) but still its not working. Can any body help?. (see the pictures) Is there any other way to have dynamic fonts?

[imports for responsive screen etc..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiaMk.png)

[using in in styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srcsu.png)

[How its should it look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oshuj.png)

[How it shouldn't but looking on Ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpsGU.png)

I sumbmited the code to Chatgbt for checking but still not resolving. I also tries RFPercentage and different second arguments while using FRValue.